# Java objects with getter and setter methods

Tags: java, if-statement

Hi can someone please help me,I am a novice programmer and I don't understand the following code.

How does `one.bark()` automatically returns the statement under the first `if` condition. How does the compiler know which if statement to display (because we are not passing the size while calling `bark()`)? I know the object calls the function `setSize` and passes the argument `70` to it. Does that mean that the value `70` becomes an attribute of the object `one`?

Code:

```
class GoodDog {
    private int size;

    public void setSize(int s) {
        size = s;
    }

    public int getSize() 
    {
        return size;
    }

    void bark()
    {
        if (size > 60)
        {
            System.out.println("Wooof! Wooof!");
        } 
        else if (size > 14) 
        {
            System.out.println("Ruff! Ruff!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Yip! Yip!");
        }
    }

}

class GoodDogTestDrive
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        GoodDog one = new GoodDog();
        one.setSize(70);
        GoodDog two = new GoodDog();
        two.setSize(8);

        System.out.println("Dog one: " + one.getSize());
        System.out.println("Dog two: " + two.getSize());
        one.bark();
        two.bark();
    }

}
```

Comment: You are invoking `bark` on an instance of `GoodDog` whose `size` instance field has been set in a previous invocation. As such the instance of `GoodDog` will retain its `size`, which will then be used to compute the logic within `bark`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When you call `one.setSize(70)`, the `size` variable is saved as `70` in the `one` object. When you call `one.bark()`, `size` is still `70`

Answer (score 0):

When creating an object of a class , the object receives a copy of all non-static members of the class.

**GoodDog one = new GoodDog();**

object **one** contains a special copy of size. Like wise object **two** will have its own copy of member variable size.

When you set the size using setSize() function , the **one** object's size variable is modified and will contain the same value until another value is assigned.

When you call the bark function using **one** function , it's own copy of size variable is taken and used inside the bark function.

Comment: so basically "one.setSize(70); " is same as " one.size= 70; " ??  can you also please explain what is the use of declaring "size" as "private" in this code?

Comment: private member variables cannot be used or manipulated outside the class ( for data security and encapsulation ) . i.e., only member functions can manipulate the value of a private member variable. Thats why we expose getter and setter methods to get and set the values of member variables.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `70` is not a new attribute, but the `size` attribute takes the value `70`.

And since you have two distinct instances (`Dog one` and `Dog two`) of GoodDog, each one has it's own attribute `size`, which has it's own value (in this case `70` and `8`).

From there, when you call the `bark` method, each instance (`one` /`two`) will check the `if/else` statement according to it's own attribute's value (respectively `70` / `8`).

Comment: @Idva can you also please explain what is the use of declaring "size" as "private" in this code?

Comment: Well, one of the major principle of OOP is encapsulation. When you're designing a Class it's always a good practice to declare every attribute as private, in order to respect this encapsulation.